# Excel 2011 - Conditional formatting (icons) applied to a range using formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I'm using Excel for Mac 2011. I have 2 rows of values ("start" and "end") and am tracking them over a course of 7 days.

I'd like to format each of the data cells such that a "check" icon is displayed if its value is greater than the value in the cell above/below it, an "!" icon if they are equal and an "x' icon if it is less.

I've been able to get the "check" and "x" to work for B2 using:

[image: icon set rule dialog box]

**2 Issues:**

1. I don't seem to be able to specify that the "!" is displayed if the 2 values are equal. Or am I missing something?
2. When I try to apply this rule to the entire range (B2:I2), it only compares the value of each successive cell in the range to $B$3:

   [image: result of rule applied to entire row]

   I tried using "=B3" instead but got the error stating relative references were not valid. Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do or do I have to create a new rule for each cell?

**And 1 more general question:**

1. which "Formula" is being referred to in the icon-sets rule dialog in the section for the "!" icon? And which formula is being referred to in the section for the "x" icon?